# Recursive method call Python BST height implementation

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

Im working on a BST class implementation in py. Unfortunately my height method is not providing the correct result. When trying t1.height() I get a result of 3 instead of 4 as expected.
I suspect part of the problem maybe the termination conditions of the recursion, particularly self.right/left == None check. However, I have to do this since calling height() on a None leaf will result in an error since None is not yet an instance of Node...

```
class Node: 
    # Implement a node of the binary search tree.
    # Constructor for a node with key and a given parent
    # parent can be None for a root node.
    def __init__(self, key, parent = None): 
        self.key = key
        self.parent = parent 
        self.left = None # We will set left and right child to None
        self.right = None
        # Make sure that the parent's left/right pointer
        # will point to the newly created node.
        if parent != None:
            if key < parent.key:
                assert(parent.left == None), 'parent already has a left child -- unable to create node'
                parent.left = self
            else: 
                assert key > parent.key, 'key is same as parent.key. We do not allow duplicate keys in a BST since it breaks some of the algorithms.'
                assert(parent.right == None ), 'parent already has a right child -- unable to create node'
                parent.right = self
        
    # Utility function that keeps traversing left until it finds 
    # the leftmost descendant
    def get_leftmost_descendant(self):
        if self.left != None:
            return self.left.get_leftmost_descendant()
        else:
            return self
    
    # TODO: Complete the search algorithm below
    # You can call search recursively on left or right child
    # as appropriate.
    # If search succeeds: return a tuple True and the node in the tree
    # with the key we are searching for.
    # Also note that if the search fails to find the key 
    # you should return a tuple False and the node which would
    # be the parent if we were to insert the key subsequently.
    def search(self, key):
        #print("entering search key= ",key," from node= ",self.key)
        if self.key == key: 
            return (True, self)
        # your code here
        elif self.key == None:
            return (False, self)
        elif key < self.key:
            #print('searching left')
            if self.left == None:
                return (False, self)
            else:
                return self.left.search(key)
        elif key > self.key:
            #print('searching right')
            if self.right == None:
                return (False, self)
            else:
                return self.right.search(key)
            
    #TODO: Complete the insert algorithm below
    # To insert first search for it and find out
    # the parent whose child the currently inserted key will be.
    # Create a new node with that key and insert.
    # return None if key already exists in the tree.
    # return the new node corresponding to the inserted key otherwise.
    def insert(self, key):
        # your code here
        # search for the spot to insert to        
        if self.search(key)[0] == True:
            #print('key already exists')
            return None
        else:
            return Node(key, self.search(key)[1])
       
    # TODO: Complete algorithm to compute height of the tree
    # height of a node whose children are both None is defined
    # to be 1.
    # height of any other node is 1 + maximum of the height 
    # of its children.
    # Return a number that is th eheight.
    def height(self):
        # your code here
        if self == None:
            return 1
        elif self.right == None:
            return 1
        elif self.left == None:
            return 1

        leftheight = self.left.height()
        rightheight = self.right.height()
        
        return max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1

t1 = Node(25, None)
t2 = Node(12, t1)
t3 = Node(18, t2)
t4 = Node(40, t1)

print('-- Testing basic node construction (originally provided code) -- ')
assert(t1.left == t2), 'test 1 failed'
assert(t2.parent == t1),  'test 2 failed'
assert(t2.right == t3), 'test 3 failed'
assert (t3.parent == t2), 'test 4 failed'
assert(t1.right == t4), 'test 5 failed'
assert(t4.left == None), 'test 6 failed'
assert(t4.right == None), 'test 7 failed'
# The tree should be : 
#             25
#             /\
#         12     40
#         /\
#     None  18
#

print('-- Testing search -- ')
(b, found_node) = t1.search(18)
assert b and found_node.key == 18, 'test 8 failed'
(b, found_node) = t1.search(25)
assert b and found_node.key == 25, 'test 9 failed -- you should find the node with key 25 which is the root'
(b, found_node) = t1.search(26)
assert(not b), 'test 10 failed'
assert(found_node.key == 40), 'test 11 failed -- you should be returning the leaf node which would be the parent to the node you failed to find if it were to be inserted in the tree.'

print('-- Testing insert -- ')
ins_node = t1.insert(26)
assert ins_node.key == 26, ' test 12 failed '
assert ins_node.parent == t4,  ' test 13 failed '
assert t4.left == ins_node,  ' test 14 failed '

ins_node2 = t1.insert(33)
assert ins_node2.key == 33, 'test 15 failed'
assert ins_node2.parent == ins_node, 'test 16 failed'
assert ins_node.right == ins_node2, 'test 17 failed'



print('-- Testing height -- ')

print('height t1= ',t1.height())
assert t1.height() == 4, 'test 18 failed'
assert t4.height() == 3, 'test 19 failed'
assert t2.height() == 2, 'test 20 failed'
```

Comment: What is your definition of height?  I don't understand how t4.height() can be 3 when it is a leaf node.  Also, self is never None.  You'd get a null pointer error.

Comment: height = max node count from node to leaf including "self" but not the leafs. You are correct, self is is never none, but self.left or self.right could be pointing to None in the case of leafs

Comment: So how is t4.height() == 3?

Comment: also t4 is not a leaf node, it has a value of 40 with t1 as parent

Comment: t4 is the right child of t1=25. t4=40 has t4.left = ins_node=26 and t4.right = None. ins_node.left = None and ins_node.right = ins_node2=33. And both children of ins_node2 are = None. So for t4 has t4 + ins_node + ins_node2 = 3

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  I was looking at your picture and didn't see you made changes to the tree after that picture.  Fuller answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard definition of height (as a function, not a method) is

```
def height(node):
    if node == None:
       return 0
    else:
       return 1 + max(height(node.left), height(node.right))
```

Note that `node` is an argument, so that you easily handle the "empty" case.

In the case of your code, if `node.left` is None, then you want to return `1 + height(node.right)`.  Likewise for if `node.right` is None.

Comment: def height(self):
        # your code here
        if self == None:
            return 0
        elif self.right == None and self.left == None:
            return 1
        elif self.left == None:
            return 1 + self.right.height()
        elif self.right == None:
            return 1 + self.left.height()

        leftheight = self.left.height()
        rightheight = self.right.height()
        
        return max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1

Answer (score 0):

```
def height(self):
    # your code here
    if self == None:
        return 0
    elif self.right == None and self.left == None:
        return 1
    elif self.left == None:
        return 1 + self.right.height()
    elif self.right == None:
        return 1 + self.left.height()

    leftheight = self.left.height()
    rightheight = self.right.height()
    
    return max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).